# Looking for a way to speed up a pandas merge (or potentially another method)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Hi I recently posted a question about performing a merge in order to take a pandas dataframe and return a column that satisfies a criteria.

The full details can be found here:

[How to add a new column to a pandas df that returns the smallest value that is greater in the same group from another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257033/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-a-pandas-df-that-returns-the-smallest-value-that-is-g)

(Not sure whether I should post the whole question to keep this post self contained so I will just leave a link for now).

The solution that was given works well and as I need for smaller datasets, think less than a thousand lines.

Here is the proposed answer:

```
m=(df1.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1),on='key',suffixes=('','_y')).drop('key', 1)
                                            .query("(Code==Code_y)&(Price<=Price_y)"))
m.groupby(['Code','Price'],sort=False)['Price_y'].first().reset_index(name='New Price'
```

However when I begin to use this on larger datasets (which is a requirement of mine) it begins to slow down to an almost unusable level, think 5 minutes + for thousands of rows and completely breaks down due to memory errors once I try to increase the rows in the dataframe further.

I can't help but think that there must be a better way to perform this action in a more efficient time.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure to configure data types correctly, take only necessary fields from the Dataframe and clean unused Dataframes on the go.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with:

```
m=df1.set_index('Code').join(df2.set_index('Code'),rsuffix='_New')
df1.join(m[m.Price<=m.Price_New].groupby('Price',sort=False)['Price_New']
         .first().reset_index(drop=True))
```

---

```
  Code  Price  Price_New
0    X   4.30        4.5
1    X   2.50        2.5
2    X   4.00        4.0
3    X   1.50        1.5
4    X   0.24        0.5
5    X   1.00        1.0
6    X   1.30        1.5
7    Y   3.90        4.0
8    Y   2.60        3.0
```

Performance on the sample df:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following alternative solution to the problem. Here we iterate over distinct `Code` values and search appropriate `New Price` for every `Price`. Should be much more effecient in time and memory than the original way. Also effeciency may be enhanced with optimizations and/or `numba`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def get_all_new(pd_series, result):
    result[pd_series.name] = np.sort(pd_series.unique())

def find_new_group(pd_series, sorted_arrays):
    return pd_series.apply(lambda x: find_new(x, sorted_arrays[pd_series.name]))

def find_new(value, sorted_array):
    pos = np.searchsorted(sorted_array, value)
    return sorted_array[pos] if pos < sorted_array.size else None  # None OR value ???

if __name__ == '__main__':

    N1, N2, M1, M2 = 5, 5, 5, 5
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Code': ['X'] * N1 + ['Y'] * N2,
         'Price': np.random.randint(1, 100, N1 + N2) / 10})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Code': ['X'] * M1 + ['Y'] * M2,
         'Price': np.random.randint(1, 100, M1 + M2) / 10})
    print(df1)
    print(df2)

    all_new = dict()
    # collect all new prices for every Code
    df2.groupby('Code')['Price'].apply(lambda x: get_all_new(x, all_new))
    # find appropriate new price for every old price
    df1['New Price'] = df1.groupby('Code')['Price'].apply(lambda x: find_new_group(x, all_new))

    print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  Code  Price
0    X    7.8
1    X    6.6
2    X    3.2
3    X    0.3
4    X    4.7
5    Y    0.5
6    Y    1.1
7    Y    8.9
8    Y    6.7
9    Y    0.5
  Code  Price
0    X    6.9
1    X    4.6
2    X    2.3
3    X    7.6
4    X    2.4
5    Y    0.8
6    Y    3.4
7    Y    0.4
8    Y    4.2
9    Y    9.6
  Code  Price  New Price
0    X    7.8        NaN
1    X    6.6        6.9
2    X    3.2        4.6
3    X    0.3        2.3
4    X    4.7        6.9
5    Y    0.5        0.8
6    Y    1.1        3.4
7    Y    8.9        9.6
8    Y    6.7        9.6
9    Y    0.5        0.8
```

Testes the code with `N1, N2, M1, M2 = ...`

`100_000` - `518 ms ± 2.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`,

`1_000_000` - `5.29 s ± 72.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`.